Someone sent all the money out of my wallet to another wallet. I did not make that transaction. Can I find out where it went
I just had money sent to my wallet from a Bitcoin ATM. As soon as it arrives it is being sent away. I did not send anything. Now it is all gone.

This question is similar to: Can bitcoins be traced to scammers. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
